# Joomla htaccess mobile redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile, joomla

I have 2 versions of a website, desk and mobile:

1. [www.olivashot.com](http://www.olivashot.com)
2. [www.mobile.olivashot.com](http://www.olivashot.com)

My htacces is redirecting mobile devices to the mobile version.

The **problem**...

1- If a visitor comes from **google** beacause he has searched "thing" and the full link it´s shown as "www.olivashot.com/index.php/thing" it redirects to "www.mobile.olivashot.com/index.php/thing"
(I have a happy visitor)

2- But if the link in google is: "www.olivashot.com/thing" >>> he is redirected to "www.mobile.olivashot.com" 
(I´m loosing a visitor beacuse I´m not showing what he expected)

I thing this is beause I´m rewriting "something" to quit the default "index.php" in joomla site

```
RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.




RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mobile.olivashot.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the last block **before** the Joomla custom redirect which has some exit points. This means the order should be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mobile.olivashot.com/$1/ [R=301,L]


## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
...
```

You can drop the line *RewriteEngine On* it's already enabled at the top of the file.
For added security once you get this working you can check out the boilerplate template's .htaccess file, h5bp.com